# KVO not working (observing another class's property)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, key-value-observing

I'm trying to observe a property variable (`xxx`) of `ResultDataClass`. In my working `ViewController`, I wrote the following.

```
-(void)dealloc {    
    ResultDataClass *resultData = [ResultDataClass getInstance];
    [resultData addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"xxx" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];
}

-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    self.solutionText.text = @"test1";

    if([keyPath isEqualToString:@"xxx"]) {
        self.solutionText.text = @"test2";
    }

}
```

`solutionText` is a `UITextView` in my working `ViewController`.
After running the program, nothing was shown in the textview.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Thank you and sorry for my English.

Comment: Why are you setting things up on `self` within `dealloc`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You written the observer in `dealloc` method. There will be an issue, your object is being released when you are adding an observer, so there will be a crash when the KVO value is changed.

There is no crash and nothing is working, I think the reason is; the `dealloc` method is never called. It means your view controller is never released (potentially a leak, a strong retain cycle is there).

Instead of that add that in your viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{    
    [super viewDidLoad];
    ResultDataClass *resultData = [ResultDataClass getInstance];
    [resultData addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"xxx" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I had written in viewDidLoad method before but nothing was shown either.

Comment: @user: Will `[ResultDataClass getInstance];` return singleton instance ?

Comment: Yes. I use ResultDataClass to collect all data from the other classes.

Comment: Now it works. I just missed [super viewDidLoad];. Thank you so much again!